# Flutter tabbarview inside SliverToBoxAdapter

Tags: flutter

I'm new to flutter, and I've been trying for days to put a tabbarview inside the SliverToBoxAdapter, but all the ways I tried it didn't work, I need each selection to show different information
[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nfyxD.png)

```
class _StatsScreenState extends State<StatsScreen> {
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
 return Scaffold(
   backgroundColor: Palette.primaryColor,
   appBar: CustomAppBar(),
   body: CustomScrollView(
     physics: ClampingScrollPhysics(),
     slivers: <Widget>[
       _buildHeader(),
       _buildRegionTabBar(),
     ],
   ),
 );
}

SliverPadding _buildHeader() {
 return SliverPadding(
   padding: const EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
   sliver: SliverToBoxAdapter(
       child: Text(
     'Estatisticas',
     style: const TextStyle(
       color: Colors.white,
       fontSize: 25.0,
       fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
     ),
   )),
 );
}

SliverToBoxAdapter _buildRegionTabBar() {
 return SliverToBoxAdapter(
   child: DefaultTabController(
     length: 2,
       child: TabBar(
         tabs:[
           Tab(text: 'Brasil'),
           Tab(text: 'Mundo'),    
         ],
       ),
   ),
   );
   
}
}
```